# Using display:flex property to create a responsive (horizontally laid out) nav bar

Tags: html, css

For a mobile website, I have to display 5 elements in a responsive navbar. For small resolutions, I want them to pile up vertically. But for larger ones, my aim to to lay out the 5 items like so:

[image]

I'm trying to use the `display:flex` attribute to make this work. But unfortunately, I currently have:

[image]

How do I achieve the effect I'm looking for? It's tricky to have an elegant looking responsive navbar for 5 items (which looks balanced as well). So in case you want to suggest stylistic tweaks to the way I'm doing this, I'm open to that as well.

My code is simply:

```
<div style="width:93%; max-width:400px;border: 1px solid #ccc;border-radius:4px;padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;background-color:#E8E8E8;box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);">

<div style="display:flex;">
    <span style="font-size:12px;">Option 1</span> <span style="color:purple; font-size:12px;">({{ item_count }} items)</span>
    <span style="font-size:12px;">Option 2</span> <span style="color:purple; font-size:12px;">(({{ item_count }} items)</span>
</div>
<div style="display:flex;">
    <span style="font-size:12px;">Option 3</span> <span style="color:purple; font-size:12px;">(({{ item_count }} items)</span>
    <span style="font-size:12px;">Option 4</span> <span style="color:purple; font-size:12px;">(({{ item_count }} items)</span>
</div>

<span style="font-size:12px;">{{ other_options }} other options</span>
</div>
```

The `{{` `}}` syntax is Django template tags and can be ignored. Note that all options displayed are dynamically generated and can be of variable length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All items must go in the same parent container (flex container). Don't separate them into lines. Then use flex-wrap.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item {
  flex-basis: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <span class="item">Option 1</span>
    <span class="item">Option 2</span>
    <span class="item">Option 3</span>
    <span class="item">Option 4</span>
    <span class="item">X other options</span>    
</div>
```

Feel free to change flex-basis to other value (you can use percentage like 50%), or use media queries to set it to proper value;

Answer (score 1):

I would set a relative width and flex-wrap. For desktop devices you could then tweak the width with media queries

HTML:

```
<div class="Wrapper">
  <div class="Item">Option 1</div>
  <div class="Item">Option 2</div>
  <div class="Item">Option 3</div>
  <div class="Item">Option 4</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.Wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.Item {
  width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Create an element to represent each item. Don't use two `<span>`s which aren't related to each other beyond being next to each other.
2. Put each item into a single container. Don't force your rows manually.
3. Allow wrapping with `flex-wrap: wrap;`
4. Set a size on the items so they are the width you want

```css
* {
  font-size: 12px
}

span+span {
  color: purple;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>Option 1</span> <span>({{ item_count }} items)</span></li>
  <li><span>Option 2</span> <span>(({{ item_count }} items)</span></li>
  <li><span>Option 3</span> <span>(({{ item_count }} items)</span></li>
  <li><span>Option 4</span> <span>(({{ item_count }} items)</span></li>
</ul>
<p>{{ other_options }} other options</p>
```

> For small resolutions, I want them to pile up vertically.

Use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to change the `ul` back to `display: block` to disable flexbox on narrow viewports.